# Why is Drupal urlencoding in tpl output?

Tags: 7, uri

In Drupal 7, I have

```
<?php print $some_content; ?>
```

in page.tpl.php and when the string `$some_content` contains a URL (i.e., <a href="some-url?parameters=1|2|3|5"> ... )

the URL gets urlencoded and parameters is shown as:

```
parameters=1%7C%7C2%7C3%7C5
```

where | is substituted by %7C. For aesthetic reasons I want Drupal to stop this conversion, but even if I try with urldecode(), it does not work, as it seems to be hard-coded on Drupal core itself.

How can I override this which is just a simple line in pure PHP?

Comment: _For aesthetic reasons_ Really? You wouldn't rather the URL was valid instead of being invalid?

Comment: You are completely right. My boss demands things that are out of me, out of this world and gets me crazy. Sorry for the outburst.

Comment: No apology necessary, if that's an "outburst" then your boss is a lucky person ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal is not URL encoding in the template output, it doesn't try to make that sort of blind string replace anywhere.

If the URL was prepared using any of Drupal's `url()` function, which is likely if you're using well written modules, then you should expect the query parameters to be properly encoded.

Drupal tries hard to conform to standards, you're probably going to find it more trouble than it's worth to get it to produce an invalid URL (which your desired result would be); it would be easier to simply write your own invalid version of `url()` and use that to prepare the content.